# The greatest lower bound - Signed Measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two finite signed measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal A )$. The function $\mu\wedge\nu$ is given by$$(\mu\wedge\nu)(E)=\inf\{\mu(A)+\nu(E\setminus A):~A\in\mathcal A, A\subset E\}, ~\forall E\in\mathcal A.$$
Show that:$$\mu\wedge\nu=\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|),$$
where $|\mu-\nu|$ is the total variation of $\mu-\nu$.

I already show that $\mu\wedge\nu\ge\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|)$: Indeed, Denotes $\lambda=\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|)$. Then we have
$$\lambda=\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|)\le\frac12(\mu+\nu-\mu+\nu|)=\nu.$$
Similarly, $\lambda\le\mu.$

For any $E\in \mathcal A$, fixed $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $A\in\mathcal A, A\subset E$ such that
$$(\mu\wedge\nu)(E)+\varepsilon\ge\mu(A)+\nu(E\setminus A)\ge\lambda(A)+\lambda(E\setminus A)=\lambda(E).$$
This inequality holds for $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary, thus we get

$$\mu\wedge\nu\ge\lambda= \frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|).$$

For the conversely inequality, I guess that if $\gamma$ is a signed measure on $(X,\mathcal A)$ such that $\gamma\le\mu$ and $\gamma\le\nu$ then

$$\gamma\le\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|).$$
But I have no idea to do this. Can someone please help me. thanks

Comment: How do you define the total variation $|\cdot |$?

Comment: $|\mu|=\mu^++\mu^−$, where $\{\mu^+,\mu^−\}$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$. We have a result about the total variation
$$|\mu|(A)=\sup\{\sum |\mu(E_i)|:(E_i)\subset\mathcal A\text{ is finite and disjoint sequence with }\bigcup E_i=A\}.$$

Comment: And how about $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$? Do you know how to write what they are explicitly?

Comment: You can see the definitions at here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680896/jordan-decomposition-theorem-question-to-singularity?rq=1

Comment: I was wondering whether you can use $\mu^+(E) = \sup\{ \mu(A): \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E\} $.

Comment: What is this step $\lambda=\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|)\le\frac12(\mu+\nu-\mu+\nu|)=\nu$?

Comment: Because $|\mu|\ge\mu$

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you've already got the Jordan decomposition, then you should be able to show this directly.

\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{2}\big(\mu(E) + \nu(E) - |\mu - \nu|(E)\big) = \frac{1}{2}\big(\mu(E) + \nu(E) - [(\mu - \nu)^+(E) + (\mu - \nu)^-(E)]\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\big(\mu(E) + \nu(E) - [\sup\{\mu(A) - \nu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \} - \inf\{\mu(A) - \nu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \}]\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\big(\mu(E) + \inf\{\nu(A) - \mu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \} + \nu(E) + \inf\{\mu(A) - \nu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \}\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\big(\inf\{\mu(E) + \nu(A) - \mu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \} + \inf\{\nu(E) + \mu(A) - \nu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \}\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\big(\inf\{\mu(E \setminus A) + \nu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \} + \inf\{\nu(E \setminus A) + \mu(A) : \mathcal{A} \ni A \subset E \}\big)\\
&=  \frac{1}{2}(\nu \wedge \mu)(E) + \frac{1}{2}(\mu \wedge \nu)(E) = (\mu \wedge \nu)(E).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. But I have another exercise and it says that: If $\gamma$ is a signed measure on $(X,\mathcal A)$ such that $\gamma\le\mu$ and $\gamma\le\nu$ then

$$\gamma\le\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|).$$

Comment: How to prove this?

Comment: Is this a separate question? If so, please make a separate post.

Comment: On second thought, this is an easy consequence of the equality proved above: $$\inf \{\mu(A) + \nu(E \setminus A) : A \subset E\} \geq \inf\{ \gamma(A) + \gamma(E \setminus A) : A \subset E\} = \gamma(E).$$ Now use the result above on the left-hand side.

Comment: Can we get the inequality in my exercise directly?

Comment: Sure, it follows from the _equality_ above. If you want a different proof, you have to start by defining the measure $|\mu|$. (The post you linked to does not define $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$; in my answer, I used what I think are the standard definitions.) How, for instance, do you know that $|\mu| \geq \mu$?

Comment: We have $\mu(E)\le|\mu(E)|=|\mu^+(E)-\mu^-(E)|\le|\mu^+(E)|+|\mu^-(E)|=\mu^+(E)+\mu^-(E)=|\mu|(E)$ since $\mu^+,\mu^-$ are two positive measures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55650/discussion-between-quyle-and-aduh).